# How can I measure the time it takes for each iteration of a for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, time, batch-processing

How can i use a script like this to record the time it takes for each iteration of a for loop inside a batch script? I've implemented this to record an entire script's execution time but I'd like to get durations for each iteration of a for loop.

```
    @echo off

    rem ******************  MAIN CODE SECTION
    set STARTTIME=%TIME%

    rem Your code goes here (remove the ping line)
    ping -n 4 -w 1 127.0.0.1 >NUL

    set ENDTIME=%TIME%

    rem ******************  END MAIN CODE SECTION


    rem Change formatting for the start and end times
    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%STARTTIME%") do (
       set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
    )

    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%ENDTIME%") do (
       set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
    )

    rem Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting values
    set /A elapsed=end-start

    rem Format the results for output
    set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
    if %hh% lss 10 set hh=0%hh%
    if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
    if %ss% lss 10 set ss=0%ss%
    if %cc% lss 10 set cc=0%cc%

    set DURATION=%hh%:%mm%:%ss%,%cc%

    echo Start    : %STARTTIME%
    echo Finish   : %ENDTIME%
    echo          ---------------
    echo Duration : %DURATION%
```

Output:

```
    Start    : 11:02:45.92
    Finish   : 11:02:48.98
             ---------------
    Duration : 00:00:03,06
```

**EDIT:** This is how my implementation looks

```
@ECHO on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

RMDIR c:\path1 /s /q
mkdir c:\path1
xcopy "\\path2\*" c:\path1 /s /i
cd c:\path3

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
cd c:\path1

sqlcmd -S server -i "\\path2\DropDatabases.sql"

for /D /r %%F IN ("*") DO ( 
    for %%G  IN ("%%F\*.extenstion1") DO xcopy "%%G" c:\path2\%newest% /y /i

    for /l %%A in (1,1,5) do (
        set STARTTIME=!TIME!

    for /f "delims=_" %%J IN ('forfiles /p "%%F" /m *.jmpt /c "cmd /c echo @path"')  DO start "program"  /D "c:\path3" /Wait program -r  %%J

    set ENDTIME=!TIME!
call :GetDuration !STARTTIME! !ENDTIME! 
    )
)

    exit /b
    :GetDuration
    set function_starttime=%1
    set function_endtime=%2

    rem Change formatting for the start and end times
    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%function_starttime%") do (
        set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%function_endtime%") do (
        set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

    rem Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting values
    set /A elapsed=end-start

    rem Format the results for output
    set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
    if %hh% lss 10 set hh=0%hh%
    if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
    if %ss% lss 10 set ss=0%ss%
    if %cc% lss 10 set cc=0%cc%

    set DURATION=%hh%:%mm%:%ss%.%cc%

    echo Start    : %function_starttime%
    echo Finish   : %function_endtime%
    echo          ---------------
    echo Duration : %DURATION%
    echo.

sqlcmd -S server -i "\\path2\query.sql"

pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the starttime and endtime variables at either end of the inside of your for loop code block, and put all of the conversion and output code into a function. You'll also need to enable delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

rem ******************  MAIN CODE SECTION
for /l %%A in (1,1,5) do (
    set STARTTIME=!TIME!

    rem Your code goes here (remove the ping line)
    ping -n 3 -w 1 127.0.0.1 >NUL

    set ENDTIME=!TIME!
    call :GetDuration !STARTTIME! !ENDTIME!
)

rem ******************  END MAIN CODE SECTION
exit /b

:GetDuration
set function_starttime=%1
set function_endtime=%2

rem Change formatting for the start and end times
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%function_starttime%") do (
   set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%function_endtime%") do (
   set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

rem Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting values
set /A elapsed=end-start

rem Format the results for output
set /A hh=elapsed/(60*60*100), rest=elapsed%%(60*60*100), mm=rest/(60*100), rest%%=60*100, ss=rest/100, cc=rest%%100
if %hh% lss 10 set hh=0%hh%
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
if %ss% lss 10 set ss=0%ss%
if %cc% lss 10 set cc=0%cc%

set DURATION=%hh%:%mm%:%ss%.%cc%

echo Start    : %function_starttime%
echo Finish   : %function_endtime%
echo          ---------------
echo Duration : %DURATION%
echo.
```

Comment: okay so I'm a little confused. I have almost zero experience with batch functions, are you creating functions in that code or are they just place holders?

Comment: Everything from `:GetDuration` to the end of the script is the GetDuration function. You call it with `call` like it's its own script. Parameters work the same way as well. Functions generally end with the command `goto :eof`, which goes to the end of the file, but since it's the last thing in the script in this case I can leave it off.

Comment: so should `:GetDuration` go outside the loop?

Comment: Yes! The code I've provided is a fully functioning example. In order for it to fit your needs, all you have to do is replace the `ping` command with your code (and change the type of loop).

Comment: okay small additional question, what about if the loop I want to measure is actually inside another for loop?

Comment: Nothing really changes; the starttime and endtime need to surround the part of the code to be tested. If you're testing the inner loop, set the variables inside the inner loop. If you're testing the outer loop, set the variables inside the outer loop but outside the inner loop.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was thinking. Its definitely working much closer to desired than it ever has but now its indefinitely looping. I'll post how I've implemented it in an edit above.

Comment: @David, the `for /l` was just an example loop; it's not required for the code to work.

Comment: The only problem with the script now is that I have a sqlcmd executing at the very end of the script after the start/finish/duration are echoed and this is getting done after evrey single file in the loop is run. I really like that its getting the start and finish time after each iteration but is there a simple way I can close off that loop so that it will only execute the sqlcmd line after its finished running all files?

Comment: I think its because the GetDuration function is being called in the loop but there's nothing stopping it from reading the sqlcmd after the time stuff. How can I block off that section?

Comment: Put the sqlcmd line on a line between the `)` and `REM END MAIN CODE SECTION`, which is outside the for loop but before the script is ended by `exit /b`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice package called "tictoc"
You simply put tic(i) at the beginning of a loop and toc() at the end of a loop. After each iteration, you see the exact time in secs spent on it.

More info you can find here

https://cran.rproject.org/web/packages/tictoc/tictoc.pdf

Comment: typo in link. It's `https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tictoc/tictoc.pdf`. It's about `R` (nothing to do with `batch-file`)